# Create one to many relation in FuelPHP

Tags: php, database-design, orm, fuelphp

I have 3 models: Client, Task and Taskstatus(for matching tasks for each client).
Model_Task

```
protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    );
```

Model_Client

```
protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    );
```

Model_Taskstatus

```
protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'client',
        'task',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    );
```

I have added following to Model_Task

```
protected static $_has_many = array(
        'taskstatuses' => array(
            'key_from' => 'id',
            'model_to' => 'Model_Taskstatus',
            'key_to' => 'task',
            'cascade_save' => true,
            'cascade_delete' => false,
        )
    );
```

Model_Client

```
protected static $_has_many = array(
        'taskstatuses' => array(
            'key_from' => 'id',
            'model_to' => 'Model_Taskstatus',
            'key_to' => 'client',
            'cascade_save' => true,
            'cascade_delete' => false,
        )
    );
```

Model_Taskstatus

```
protected static $_belongs_to = array(
        'client' => array(
            'key_from' => 'client',
            'model_to' => 'Model_Client',
            'key_to' => 'id',
            'cascade_save' => true,
            'cascade_delete' => false,
        ),
        'task' => array(
            'key_from' => 'task',
            'model_to' => 'Model_Task',
            'key_to' => 'id',
            'cascade_save' => true,
            'cascade_delete' => false,
        )
    );
```

I want the taskstatus linked the client field to Client model, and task field to Task model, and if user insert a task with values which are not in Client or Task model (via id), an error should appear. But it does not work (I can still add to clientstatus the value of client's id and task's id that doesn't exist in client and task tables.

Comment: What doesn't work? "Doesn't work" is not an error message! Describe what you are doing and what you want to happen.

Comment: I want client and task field in the taskstatus must be linked to id field in Client and Task model. I just added 2 clients and 2 tasks. I expect that if I insert taskstatus  with value client = 40 and task = 13 for example, an error occur telling me that the I cannot do that. But actually I still can insert taskstatus with client and task value >2, which I don't expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick with the [Model convention](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/packages/orm/creating_models.html), the following will work just fine:

```
class Model_Task extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_belongs_to = array(
        'client'
    );

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'client_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    );
}

class Model_Client extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_has_many = array(
        'task'
    );

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    );
}
```

To get the tasks of a Client, you just have to do:

```
$client = Model_Client::find(1);

foreach($client->task as $task)
{
    /* do something with each $task */
}
```

**Edit:**
That way you avoid having an unnecessary table/model between Client/Task, forcing you to add valid tasks to existing clients. Besides, if you want a **One to Many** relationship between Client/Task, using a Model_Taskstatus would allow you to assign the same task to different clients, and that is not what you want.

You should check the [Has Many](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/packages/orm/relations/has_many.html) documentation.

Comment: Actually I have a standard checklist which applied for all clients. Therefore I have to follow up for 1 client, what tasks are done and what are not. Therefore I think the relation is not between Client and Task, but the Client/Task and taskstatus. I have checked the Has Many Documentation, but don't understand the "establishing and breaking has-many relations" (where should it put to - Controller, Model? In what method? What does it mean by 6 in "Model_Comment::find(6)"). Sorry because I'm totally new to FuelPHP and the documentation seem not specific enough to me.

Comment: In the `foreach()` iteration example that I posted, you could check the state of each task associated with a client.
Besides the Has Many documentation, you should check the [Creating models](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/packages/orm/creating_models.html) and all the [ORM documentation](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/packages/orm/intro.html), for that matter.
`Model_Comment::find(6)` means that you want to fetch the `Model_Comment` where the id = 6.